# javascript convert all functions

Tags: javascript

How can i walk a object/array and convert all functions to a unique ID?

abit like

**JSON.stringify**

but only for functions

**Function.stringify(obj/arr)**

```
var sum = function(a,b){return a+b}

Function.stringify({
   foo: sum,
   bar: [{
      baz: [["foo", "bar"], "baz", function(){}]
   }]
})

// returns 

{
   foo: "func01",
   bar: [{
      baz: [["foo", "bar"], "baz", "func02"]
   }]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.

Comment: When stringifying an object to JSON, he wants each function to be  encoded as a string unique ID instead of being omitted from the JSON.

Comment: i don't actually want to stringify a hole object just the functions

Comment: @Endless, like Jeopardy, you'll need to phrase this post in the form of a question. It'll help if you show [*what you've tried*](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: @zzzzBov But in Jeopardy, the **answer** is in the form of a question. The question is in the form of an answer. In terms of Jeopardy, the OP is valid. In terms of SO, it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like the following, though I didn't bother with the padding for the function counter:

```
var mySerializer = function () {
  var counter = 0;

  return function serialize(input, stack, reset) {
    var result, prop, funcId, i;

    if (reset) {
      counter = 0;
    }

    if (typeof stack !== 'object') {
      stack = {};
    }

    switch (typeof input) {
      // input is object
      case 'object':
        result = {};
        for (prop in input) {
          if (input.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            result[prop] = serialize(input[prop], stack, false);
          }
        }
        break;

      // input is array
      case 'array':
        result = [];
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i += 1) {
          result.push(serialize(input[i], stack, false));
        }
        break;

      case 'function':
        funcId = ['func', ++counter].join('');
        funcs[funcId] = input;
        return funcId;

      // default
      default:
        return input;
    }

    return result;
  };
}();

var
  sum = function(a,b){ return a+b; },
  funcs = {},
  result = mySerializer({
    foo: sum,
    bar: [{
      baz: [["foo", "bar"], "baz", function(){}]
    }]
  }, funcs); // supply empty object, which will be used to stored replaced functions

console.log(result, funcs);
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ujahub/1/

---

*updated to make the "replaced" functions accessible.*

Comment: Thank you! i did a own soulution as well with the help of JSON
http://jsfiddle.net/gHMU4/1

Comment: @Endless: Seriously, don't use that solution. There's no need to `.stringify` then `.parse`. You based it on a bad solution that made incorrect assumptions about your question. A simple recursive function is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second argument to `JSON.stringify`: `replacer`:

```
function func() {}
var data = {
    "some data": func
};
JSON.stringify(data, function (key, value) {
    if (value === func) {
        return "**func";
    }
    return value;
});
// output: {"some data": "**func"}
```

It's easy enough to change this code to handle an arbitrary number of functions.

This does require you to *know* all your functions and de-serialization is also an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun...

```
function getAllFunctions()
{
   var functionBodies = [];

    //iterate through keys of window object
    for (var f in window) 
    {
        if (window.hasOwnProperty(f) && typeof window[f] === 'function')
        {
            //ignore native functions
            if(window[f].toString().match(/(\[native code\]|\[object Function\])/g) == null)
            {
                functionBodies.push(window[f].toString());
            }
        }
    }

    return functionBodies.join('\n\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with the idea from Frits i came up with my own solution

```
var id = 0;
func = {};

function mySerializer(data){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === "function") {
            func["func"+id] = value;
            id++;
            return "func"+id;
        }
        return value;
    }));
}

var sum = function(a,b){ return a+b; };

console.log(mySerializer({
   foo: sum,
   bar: [{
      baz: [["foo", "bar"], "baz", function(){}]
   }]
}));
```

Comment: How are you going to handle the de-serialization? or did you just want to get rid of the functions?

Comment: Since you *clearly* stated in your question that all you want to do is affect the functions in your object, why would you use `.serialize` and `.parse`? This seems to be major overkill.

Comment: `stringify` walks the structure for you, certainly not a trivial thing in JavaScript (@cvsguimaraes got it wrong). JSON parsing is _extremely_ fast in JavaScript. Would you be interested in making a benchmark? Custom walker + replace vs parse + stringify.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: It all depends. Some JavaScript data isn't able to be serialized to JSON. There could be data loss. And if all you're doing is replacing the functions, there shouldn't be too much to it. http://jsfiddle.net/VJ6HH/

Comment: True, `JSON.stringify` can't deal with recursive structures or native objects like `Functions` or `DOMElements`. There wont be data-loss though, it'll just throw an Error. But since OP is in the mindset of serializing I think it was safe to make the assumption that none of these are the case. Like I said, writing a bug-free walker is non-trivial so there is definitely _"something to it"_

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: There can be data loss in the result. A generalized recursive approach can be tough, as it would need to cover multiple situations. But if all the data is being left alone except for functions, then it's simple. OP just needs to decide if there could be circular references, and how inherited properties should be treated.

Comment: in my situation the amont i need to serialize is not much. has nothing to do with DOM or circular reference

Comment: @Endless: Just keep in mind that you're limited to numbers, strings, boolean and null *(and arrays and objects of course)*. No regular expressions or properties that have `undefined`, for example.